# How to run multiple Alter stored procedure scripts as a single one ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to alter like 10 stored procedures, each of one I got the script for. I want to put these Alter SP scripts in one single SQL Server script file and run it all at once. I copied all the alter SP scripts in one single file but it didn't work : says Alter Table statement should be the first one ..blah blah

**How do I create a single script that will run ALL the Alter scripts at once?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create an SQL file in that writes `Go` after each procedure.

Your file structure will be like as below :

```
stored procedure 1

Go 

stored procedure 1\2

Go 

...

stored procedure n

Go
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate your script files as Pranay Rana suggests.

But if you're using SQLCMD.EXE, it may be easier just to include existing files with the ":r" command:

```
:r File1.sql
:r File2.sql
...
```

See [the MSDN documentation for SQLCMD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)